# How do I find IP address of user in mysql error log

Tags: mysql

I have a stream of errors in the mySQL error log

```
170311 14:29:49 [Warning] Access denied for user 'root'@'travelexpert.orion.rs' (using password: YES)
```

I have searched for *travelexpert* in apache access and error logs.

How do I fid the IP address of whoever is accessing so I can block it?

Comment: Resolve the hostname?

Comment: [77.105.37.120] You're welcome.

Comment: I did that, but I thought that was the target rather than the origin.  doh!  Thanks